# Loaded model gives either 0 or 1 with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, kaggle

Im using Kaggle to train my model. My model definition is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB4
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

base_model = EfficientNetB4(input_tensor=Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
                            weights='imagenet',
                            include_top=False,
                            pooling='avg'
                           )
x=base_model.output
output=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

After fitting the model, I'm saving the model with this:

```
MODEL_DIR = "../working/tfx_model/"
version = "alpha"
export_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, str(version))
print('export_path = {}\n'.format(export_path))

tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model,
    export_path,
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None,
    options=None
)

print('\nSaved model:')
!ls -l {export_path}
```

Im simply importing the model to my local computer with the following:

```
model = load_model('models/tfx_model')
```

However the result of `model.predict(input_image)` returns an array of 0 or 1. However on Kaggle, I can have the confidence values.

I have already suspected a weird bug with EfficientNet implementation of Keras yet I haven't found anything on the subject. Also I tried saving .h5 and weights only and it had still the same issue.

The model is not over-fitted.

Kaggle environment versions:

```
'Tensorflow Version 2.9.2,Keras Version:2.9.0'
```

Local environment versions:

```
'Tensorflow Version 2.10.0,Keras Version:2.10.0'
```

Comment: it your kaggle notebook public? If so, please share.

Comment: If you can provide me you Kaggle username in DMs I can give you access for it.

Comment: No, that would be unfair to other. Please provide minimum reproducible code that can be shared publicly.

Comment: This is the fork of it.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/batuhaneralpofficial/fork-of-kaggle-effnet-approach

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to different **keras versions**.

To get the probabilities try:

```
model.predict_proba(input_image)
```

After a certain keras version (I think 2.6), `predict` and `predict_proba` return probabilities but for previous versions `predict` returns 0 or 1

Comment: Im already using model.predict. Im updating the question with my versions.

Comment: Sorry   model.predict_proba I wanted to say.

Comment: It didn't work AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'